# objects with state and behavior in oop

Tags: oop, object-oriented-analysis

I keep hearing the term object has behavior and state or just one of them. But what is the difference or what does it mean, and if anyone can give an example I would really appreciate it.

Comment: State is a state. An apple is green, red, maybe yellow and sooner or later rotten. Not that diffrent with objects. Please be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 35):

- Lamp is an object.
- The "state" in lamp:on and off.
- The "behavior" in lamp:turn on and turn off.

In programming you declare states in "fields" and behaviors in "methods" etc..

Read and learn [object-oriented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

Comment: properties are behavior or state?

Comment: properties would be considered as state

Answer (score 10):

```
class Door {
  boolean isOpen;

  void close(){
    isOpen = false;
  }
}
```

Look at this simple snippet.
We have class `Door`, it has a **state** `isOpen` - variable describes current state of this door. Method `close` it is **behaviour** of door, when we call it, we change current state of object.

I advice you to read good for beginners book about object oriented programming: [Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678). If you read it you get better understanding.

Comment: properties are behavior or state?

Answer (score 5):

```
abstract class Animal
{
   int age;
   abstract void Run();
}

class Tiger:Animal
{
    override void Run()
    {
      //something.
    }
}

main()
{
     Tiger t1 = new Tiger();
     Tiger t2 = new Tiger();
     t1.age = 25;
     t2.age = 10;
}
```

Now you have created two Tiger objects. `Tiger` can `Run`. That is the behavior of the object `Tiger`. `t1 age` is `25` and `t2 age` is `10`. `t1.age, t2.age` is the state of the object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Objects are defined by methods and fields.

> fields or state can be thought of current conditions within an object. A banana's state would be its shape and colour and size
>   Methods or behaviours can be thought of its acting. With the banana, whether it is ripe or dry can be the behaviour.